# UWP App will not build using windows-latest (windows 2022) on Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, uwp, yaml

I am trying to build a UWP app using the latest version of windows for my vmImage, currently the build script looks like this:
[Build script Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6TuX.png)

```
# Universal Windows Platform
# Build a Universal Windows Platform project using Visual Studio.
# Add steps that test and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'ARM'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  appxPackageDir: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\'
```

And whenever I try to use a vmImage to use `windows-latest` or `windows-2022` it gives me multiple `Error CS0234` for namespace `Windows`, `System` and many more things, is it possible to build UWP apps using `windows-2022`? Or am I missing something.

Other people have mentioned they solved their problem but their platform was ARMx64 and the solution did not apply to my problem

Comment: Have you tried restoring also your Nuget packages before the build? Is the restore performed?

Comment: Yes I have and it is being done, unfortunately no luck